# Counting up with no repeating digits in a number

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, arraylist, counter

I'm trying to optimize my programm counter. It depends on the size of the number (from 3 to 10 digits, with no repeats) - i.g. 012, 013,214,etc. My 1st solution were *for loops*, something like this:

```
private void sample() {
        int[] varValue = new int[3];
        innerloop: for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
                if (a == b)
                    continue;
                for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
                    if (c == b)
                        continue;
                    if (c == a)
                        continue;
                    varValue[0] = a;
                    varValue[1] = b;
                    varValue[2] = c;

                    int EqOne = varValue[0] * 100 + varValue[1] * 10 + varValue[2];

                    if (EqOne == 432) {
                        System.out.println(varValue[0]);
                        System.out.println(varValue[1]);
                        System.out.println(varValue[2]);
                        break innerloop;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

or for 10 digits (https://gist.github.com/TrollerN/6a0e470c539c57fd4cd73086cf6eb41b)

Then I could add those *a, b, c* to the int[] or ArrayList and work with it. It was ok, but with 10 different digits it ment 10 *for loops* with *if* statments + I had to create 8 different methods - one for each number of digits.

I was also trying to create ArrayList of 10 digits (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), shuffle it, and return 3-10 digits, but it's could make never-ending loop for 9-10 digits numbers.

My next "great" idea (no, honestly that one was the stupidest so far :D) was to save ArrayList of combinations to file, for each case, and then load the needed one and go through it to find solution.

I was thinking about createing some method which will take the number of digits ("so it knows how many loops it needs") and/or last solution so it knows were to start.

EDIT:
I've modified the question with sample method. Of Course the int EqOne and If statment are much more complex, but it technicaly shows what I wanted to achieve - at least I hope :P

What I was looking for was a method, that will create as many loops and as big array/arraylist as needed?

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: You don't make it clear what this code is supposed to do which makes it impossible to answer. If i was to guess I would say it looks like you're trying to output the different permutations of a number of digits? E.g. 1+2 could be 12 or 21. With your nested for loops that you don't know how many levels will be required one solution could be recursion. It depends what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Getting the int[] or ArrayList of values with which I can work, which will keep changing and looking for a solutions.

Comment: I've modifed the question with sample method. Ofcours the _int EqOne_ and _If statment_ are much more complex, but it technicaly shows what I wanted to achieve - at least I hope :P

Comment: Can't answer now it's on hold, but see this [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/1GvQK7) for working example.

Comment: @Andreas It's open now.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want *numbers* of the given length, not strings, one way to do it is to remember which digits are currently in use using a `boolean[10]`, so they can be skipped fast.

Then keep the digits in an array and increment last digit like you would a normal number. When it rolls over, you increment the second-last digit, and so forth, resetting the trailing digits to unused numbers.

Example: If current number is `1097`, it goes like this:

```
Digits  In Use               Description
1097    0 1 _ _ _ _ _ 7 _ 9
1097    0 1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 9  Clear in-use of last digit
1098    0 1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 9  Increment last digit
1098    0 1 _ _ _ _ _ _ 8 9  Mark in-use
=======================================================
1098    0 1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 9  Clear in-use of last digit
1099    0 1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 9  Increment last digit, but it's in use
109?    0 1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 9  Rollover, so go to previous digit
109?    0 1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  Clear in-use
10??    0 1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  Rollover, so go to previous digit
10??    _ 1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  Clear in-use
11??    _ 1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  Increment digit, but it's in use
12??    _ 1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  Increment digit
12??    _ 1 2 _ _ _ _ _ _ _  Mark in-use
120?    0 1 2 _ _ _ _ _ _ _  Set to first unused digit, and mark in-use
1203    0 1 2 3 _ _ _ _ _ _  Set to first unused digit, and mark in-use
=======================================================
```

As you can see, the logic makes it go from `1097` to `1098` to `1203`.

Here is the logic for that. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/1GvQK7) for running example.

```
final class UniqueDigitCounter {
    private int[]     digits;
    private boolean[] inUse = new boolean[10];
    public UniqueDigitCounter(int digitCount) {
        if (digitCount < 1 || digitCount > 10)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid digit count: " + digitCount);
        this.digits = new int[digitCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < digitCount; i++) {
            this.digits[i] = i;
            this.inUse[i] = true;
        }
    }
    public long next() {
        if (this.digits == null)
            return -1; // end of sequence
        long value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.digits.length; i++)
            value = value * 10 + this.digits[i];
        for (int i = this.digits.length - 1; ; i--) {
            if (i == -1) {
                this.digits = null; // end of sequence
                break;
            }
            int digit = this.digits[i];
            this.inUse[digit] = false;
            if ((digit = nextDigit(digit + 1)) != -1) {
                this.digits[i] = digit;
                while (++i < this.digits.length)
                    this.digits[i] = nextDigit(0);
                break;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
    private int nextDigit(int minDigit) {
        for (int digit = minDigit; digit < 10; digit++)
            if (! this.inUse[digit]) {
                this.inUse[digit] = true;
                return digit;
            }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to generate the list you're after directly since you're not allowing repeating digits.  I think the easiest way to do this would be to first get all the n-length combinations in lexicographic order, then get all permutations of each of the combinations.  That is, for the `n = 2` case, you would generate `"01", "02", ... , "78", "79", "89"`, and then would get all of the permutations of each of those.

Here's a quick program I put together that should get you what you're after:

```
public static List<String> getCombinations (String digits, int n) {

  List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
  for ( int k = 0; k < digits.length (); ++k ) {
    if ( n == 1 )
      out.add (digits.charAt (k) + "");
    else {
      for ( String s : getCombinations (digits.substring (k + 1), n - 1) ) {
        out.add (digits.charAt (k) + s);
      }
    }
  }

  return out;
}


public static List<String> getPermutations (String s, String prefix) {

  List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();

  if ( s.length () == 1 ) {
    out.add (prefix + s);
  }
  else {
    for ( int i = 0; i < s.length (); ++i ) {
      out.addAll (getPermutations (prefix + s.charAt (i), s.substring (0, i) + s.substring (i + 1)));
    }
  }

  return out;
}


public static List<String> getPermutations (List<String> combinations) {
  List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
  for ( String s : combinations )
    out.addAll (getPermutations (s, ""));

  return out;
}


public static void main (String[] args) {

  List<String> combinations = getCombinations ("0123456789", 3);

  List<String> permutations = getPermutations (combinations);

  for ( String s : permutations ) {
    System.out.println (s);
  }

}
```